# Calculus find limit with dominance of one function over another

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

so I have this math problem, that I can't seem to wrap my head around, I have to find the integral:

$$\int_1^{\infty}{\frac{d}{dx}}\left(\frac{3\ln(x)}{x}\right)dx$$

I have no idea where to start... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful
$$\int_a^b f'(t)\,dt = f(b) - f(a).$$

Comment: I know this, however how do I handle $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $dx$ in the integral?

Comment: the $d/dx$ and ' are synonomous.

Comment: So, jut ignore it? and find the antiderivative of $\left(\frac{3\ln(x)}{x}\right)$?

Comment: No, an antiderivative of the derivative is the function itself.

Comment: So... then what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$I=\int \frac{dy(x)}{dx} dx$$ It seems that the result is just $$I=y(x)+C$$ since you just integrate a derivative. Now, use the bounds.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: I'm getting an undefined answer... is that correct?